Flutter android new gradle version setup
My app was running well until recently when Dart asked me to make changes to my gradle versions. I made the changes as recommended by the documentation documentation.
However, after following the instructions, I'm getting these errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Where:
Build file '/Users/ebenoasis/Desktop/hithcride/android/build.gradle' line: 13

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.



Build completed with 1 failures.
com/android/build/api/dsl/StoreArchive


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Am I doing anything wrong here? Please check for me
settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.2.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.20" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
}

include ":app"

** App-level build.gradle **
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.oasis.hitchride.hithcride"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.oasis.hitchride.hithcride"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.1"))
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0-beta04'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0' 
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-ktx")
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
}

project-level build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

How can I rectify this?. Everytthing was working alright until now.
